# Why *NgIf not working angular 9 with boolean value

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, angular9

i'm trying to display element with ngif on boolean like this :

```
<li *ngIf="!include == true">
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">
        <i [ngClass]="hearthClass"></i>
    </span>
</li>
```

my include var il initialized to false and switch state like this :

```
this.localStorageService.getCurrentUser().then((res) => {
      this.userProfile = res;
       if(this.song.likes.includes(this.userProfile._id)){
         this.include = true
       }
      this.classHeart();
    });
```

thank you everybody !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!` operator works first, then `==`, so when you set `include` to `true`, `ngIf` result is `false`.

Just write

```
<li *ngIf="include">
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">
        <i [ngClass]="hearthClass"></i>
    </span>
</li>
```

Comment: At first check if the value of `include` is ever changed to `true`

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `!` before `include`. Code would be like this

```
  <li *ngIf="include else notInclude">
     <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">
       <i [ngClass]="hearthClass"></i>
     </span>
  </li>
  <ng-template #notInclude></ng-template>
```

`ng-template` would be used as `else` block

Answer (score 1):

So I had the same issue.

First I am going to show how it was and how I fixed it.

Before:

```
export class SomeComponent {
  isUniquePage = true;
}
```

Html

```
<div class="col-lg-3" *ngIf="!isUniquePage">
Something
</div>
```

For some reason this wasn't working as expected. The column was always being displayed.

To make it work I just did this:

```
export class SomeComponent {
  isUniquePage : boolean = true;
}
```

After that the column hid.

It's kind of weird because then I removed the type annotation and everything worked as expected (just as I had it from the start).

I don't know why it doesn't work as expected from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I would make your localStorageService return an observable. So I would take a reactive approach to your setup.

```
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';


// define variable in your class as
// userProfile$: Observable<UserProfile>
this.userProfile$ = from(this.localStorageService
  .getCurrentUser())
  .pipe(tap() => this.classHeart()
);

// define variable in your class as
// include$: Observable<boolean>
this.include$: Observable<boolean> = this.userProfile$.pipe(
  map(user: User) => this.song.likes.includes(user._id)
);
```

```
<li *ngIf="include$ | async">
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">
        <i [ngClass]="hearthClass"></i>
    </span>
</li>
```

When we suffix a variable name with a `$` it means that this variable is an `Observable`, this is a standard within the Angular community.

Comment: i don't understand how to implement this on my code, my localstoreageservice return a promise

Comment: I adapted the code, you just need to wrap it into a ´from()´ statement normally.